# Parent node undefined in button creation

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a test build for my project, which includes a lot of data manipulation. I have two buttons inline at the end of the rows, one for editing, and one for committing the changes made.

```
    function editRow(btn) {
    var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.contentEditable = "true";
    row.focus();
}

function addRow(tableID, numberOfCells) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById(tableID);

    //create rows
    var newRow = tbl.insertRow(-1);

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfCells; i++) {
        newRow.insertCell(0);
    }

    //assignbuttons
    var lastcell = newRow.cells[numberOfCells - 1];
    addEditButton(lastcell);
    addCommitButton(lastcell);
}

function addEditButton(context) {
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "button";
    button.value = "Edit";
    button.onclick = editRow(this);
    context.appendChild(button);

}
```

The user will press the new row button, and then an empty row will appear along with the two buttons.

I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
at editRow (js.js:97)
at addEditButton (js.js:123)
at addRow (js.js:115)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems I can see.

`button.onclick = editRow(this);` the `this` would result in `undefined` (in strict mode) in that scope. You can probably fix this by sending in the button element

`button.onclick = editRow(button);`

More reading on [this in a function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context)

Also you are not creating a row with a td element to place the button in. So `btn.parentNode.parentNode` is not the `row` element as you are expecting

Try this

```js
function editRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.contentEditable = "true";
  row.focus();
}

function addRow(tableID, numberOfCells) {
  var tbl = document.getElementById(tableID);

  //create rows
  var newRow = tbl.insertRow(-1);

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < numberOfCells; i++) {
    newRow.insertCell(0);
  }

  //assignbuttons
  var lastcell = newRow.cells[numberOfCells - 1];
  addEditButton(lastcell);
  //addCommitButton(lastcell);
}

function addEditButton(context) {
  var row = document.createElement("row");
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  var button = document.createElement("input");
  button.type = "button";
  button.value = "Edit";
  td.appendChild(button);
  row.appendChild(td);
  context.appendChild(row);
  button.onclick = editRow(button);
}

addRow("myTable", 2)
```

```html
<table id="myTable">

</table>
```

Comment: Getting the same error with your suggestion. I believed I already tried that.

Comment: @JordanDowns I updated with a second problem and explination

Answer (score 0):

```
function addRow(tableID, numberOfCells) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = $("#" + tableID).html();
    if(numberOfCells === 5) {
    $("#" + tableID).html(tableHTML + "<tr id=\"bikeTableBike_new\"><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td><button id=\"editBikeButton\" class=\"tableButtons\" onclick=\"editRow(this)\"><img src=\"images/edit.png\"/></button><button id=\"deleteBikeButton\" class=\"tableButtons\" onclick=\"commitRow(this)\"><img src=\"images/commit.png\"/></button></td></tr>");
    }
    if(numberOfCells === 4) {
        $("#" + tableID).html(tableHTML + "<tr id=\"bikeTableBike_new\"><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td><button id=\"editBikeButton\" class=\"tableButtons\" onclick=\"editRow(this)\"><img src=\"images/edit.png\"/></button><button id=\"deleteBikeButton\" class=\"tableButtons\" onclick=\"commitRow(this)\"><img src=\"images/commit.png\"/></button></td></tr>");
    }
    if(numberOfCells === 3) {
        $("#" + tableID).html(tableHTML + "<tr id=\"bikeTableBike_new\"><td>-</td><td>-</td><td><button id=\"editBikeButton\" class=\"tableButtons\" onclick=\"editRow(this)\"><img src=\"images/edit.png\"/></button><button id=\"deleteBikeButton\" class=\"tableButtons\" onclick=\"commitRow(this)\"><img src=\"images/commit.png\"/></button></td></tr>");         
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it for me